# ical4j 2.2.0 using Grape, throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/configuration/Configuration when loading a calendar

Tags: groovy, ical4j

Previously I have been able to run this script that read events from a url.ics

```
import net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Calendars
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.VEvent

@Grapes(
@Grab(group='org.mnode.ical4j', module='ical4j', version='2.2.0')
)
def url = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/xxxx/basic.ics'.toURL()
def cal = Calendars.load(url)
```

However, now I am getting this exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/configuration/Configuration`.

I assume there is some sort of dependency change that has occurred. I have noted this

> javax.cache.cache-api [optional*] - Supports caching timzeone definitions. * NOTE: when not included you must set a value for the net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl configuration

however, now I am getting this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.fortuna.ical4j.validate.AbstractCalendarValidatorFactory`

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ical4j looks for a properties file called `ical4j.properties` and loads configuration from it. Create this file in the same folder and add

```
net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl=net.fortuna.ical4j.util.MapTimeZoneCache
```

to specify in-memory cache provider that uses `ConcurrentHashMap`. When property `net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl` is not specified, ical4j falls back to `JCacheTimeZoneCache` which uses cache manager and requires valid caching library to be present in the classpath.

The alternative to using `ical4j.properties` file is to set this property programatically, e.g.

```
System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", "net.fortuna.ical4j.util.MapTimeZoneCache")
```

Just remember to set it before calling `Calendars.load(url)` and it should work.

Comment: The difficulty here is that I do not have the file locally, I am use grape to handle the dependency managment [link](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html)

So I have to do it in code something like

`System.properties.'net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl' = 'net.fortuna.ical4j.util.MapTimeZoneCache'`

this changes the exception to `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.fortuna.ical4j.validate.AbstractCalendarValidatorFactory`

the weird this is it was working fine a month ago

Comment: @narayanatakacs It works with Grapes as well - this properties file can be added next to your Groovy script file and it will be seen in the classpath. Alternatively you can set this property with `System.setProperty()` method, I've updated the answer to cover this use case as well.